# iOS 13 UIView screenshotting is not working properly. Working fine iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I've a problem screenshotting a main UIView containing a subview showing a video stream inside it. When I take a screenshot the image is correct less the rectangle with the video stream that is black, stream image is not showed !

The screenshot bugged
[bad screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxj3K.jpg)

and the correct image
[correct screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R7lI.jpg)

The iOS versione is 13.2.3 and the same code works properly on iOS 12. I tried using UIGraphicsImageRenderer and renderer.image

```
guard let layer = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.layer else { return }
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: layer.frame.size)
let image = renderer.image(actions: { context in
     layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
 })
```

also tried with drawHierarchy

```
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: view.bounds.size)
let image = renderer.image { context in
    view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
}
```

and other ways always with the same bad result.

It seems similar to [iOS 13 UITextView converting UITextView to image is not working properly. Working fine in below iOS 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58405106/ios-13-uitextview-converting-uitextview-to-image-is-not-working-properly-workin/59123412?noredirect=1#comment104476017_59123412)

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you got any solution?

Comment: @AshishKakkad at this time I found any solution for that issue

Comment: Then post it..... @aldopa